# JavaScript - Filter out similar strings in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, list, filter, compare

I have printed result from an array which looks like following;

```
A250.1 - 0h 34 m
A450.1 - 0h 34 m
A240.2 - 1h 34 m
A510.2 - 1h 34 m
A440.2 - 1h 34 m
A520.7 - 1h 34 m
A350.1 - 3h 19 m
A450.3 - 3h 34 m
A340.1 - 3h 34 m
A250.1 - 3h 34 m
A320.6 - 3h 34 m
A210.2 - 4h 19 m
A240.4 - 5h 34 m
A240.2 - 5h 34 m
```

So we have here **A250.1 - 0h 34 m** and **A250.1 - 3h 34 m**. What is the most efficient way to filter out the second one with the same name (**A250.1 - 3h 34 m**) from the first one (**A250.1 - 0h 34 m**)? (The other A250.1 will pop back to visible, when the first ones time expires.

TO CLARIFY; When the time expires it no longer shows the element in the filtered array.

I would like the result look like following;

```
A250.1 - 0h 34 m
A450.1 - 0h 34 m
A240.2 - 1h 34 m
A510.2 - 1h 34 m
A440.2 - 1h 34 m
A520.7 - 1h 34 m
A350.1 - 3h 19 m
A450.3 - 3h 34 m
A340.1 - 3h 34 m
A320.6 - 3h 34 m
A210.2 - 4h 19 m
A240.4 - 5h 34 m
A240.2 - 5h 34 m

// REMOVED (2nd) A250.1 - 3h 34 m
```

Some further information about this can bee looked at here;
[JavaScript - Comparing two arrays with same strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43777914/javascript-comparing-two-arrays-with-same-strings)

Comment: posible duplicate of this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960473/unique-values-in-an-array

Comment: @subbu1191 Not a duplicate.

Comment: It's so un clear i dont even know witch part is unclear. Even the previous question do not help.

Answer (score 0):

```
 var input_array = [
     "A250.1 - 0h 34 m",
     "A450.1 - 0h 34 m",
     "A240.2 - 1h 34 m",
     "A510.2 - 1h 34 m",
     "A440.2 - 1h 34 m",
     "A520.7 - 1h 34 m",
     "A350.1 - 3h 19 m",
     "A450.3 - 3h 34 m",
     "A340.1 - 3h 34 m",
     "A250.1 - 3h 34 m",
     "A320.6 - 3h 34 m",
     "A210.2 - 4h 19 m",
     "A240.4 - 5h 34 m",
     "A240.2 - 5h 34 m"
 ];
 var output_array = []
 var tmp_array = []
 for (var i = 0; i < input_array.length - 1; i++) {
     var result = input_array[i].split(' - ');
     if (tmp_array.indexOf(result[0]) == -1) {
         tmp_array.push(result[0]);
         output_array.push(result[0].concat(' - ' + result[1]))
     }
 }
 console.log(output_array);
```

Try this code,it will work.
Check on https://codepad.remoteinterview.io/LLPNUEZDFT